# ASP.NET MVC 2 & IIS : HTTP 500.24 favicon.ico Error

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-2, httprequest, fiddler, favicon

I have a little weird behavior with my ASP.NET MVC 2 application.

I'm using IIS 7.5, Windows Authentication and ASP.NET Impersonation for my webpage to load.

After several searches, I didn't found a nice way to get rid of the 500.24 Request that I keep getting on every page load (The favicon.ico at the root directory triggers this) :

[image: Fiddler]

I've looked at some articles like [this one](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/12/08/IIS-7.0-Breaking-Changes-ASP.NET-2.0-applications-Integrated-mode.aspx) or [that one](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx) but this doesn't seems to solve my issue. I need these settings on for my application to work here : .NET 4 Framework Integrated Mode pipeline, Windows Authentification and ASP.NET Impersonation.

Here's a simplified version of my web.config, if it can help anyone (of course, I've removed the connections strings for security reasons..)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Windows">
      <!-- roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" / -->
      <!-- forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" / -->
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/Globe" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/Globe" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/Globe" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/Globe" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <verbs>
          <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
          <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
        </verbs>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My application IS working, the favicon.ico IS loading, I'm just wondering why it does fires a 500.24 on every request (Of course, maybe it's Fiddler who can't authenticate itself and causes de 500.24 HTTP Error, but when it does normally it triggers a 401.2 - Unauthorized instead...)

Comment: on the web the quick suggestion looks to be its the impersonation = true. Have you tried moving to Classic mode (suggested by many links) to see if it works. as I guess the "<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />" did not work for you

Comment: I can't go with Classic Mode, since my application requires the integrated pipeline, and both the `<identity impersonate="true" />` and `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />` are already enforced in my web.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that favicon.ico is either running in a different application pool, or there is a web.config in the root of the site that has issues.
So:
1) Check to see if the root of the site (the directory where /favicon.ico lives) includes a web.config. If it does, then check to see if it is setting a system.web/httpModule, or httpHandler, or system.web/identity (impersonate) or something like that, and the application pool is running in integrated mode.

So what you need to do is either remove the offending httpmodule/httphandler/impersonate setting, or change the application pool to run as classic, or add the same configuration your site includes which is <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

Comment: I'll look into this, however I do need the integrated pipeline, and the `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />` does nothing to me. There is a generated web.config indeed in the C:\inetpub\wwwroot, I've tried adding the `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />` to the wwwroot web.config, and still doesn't make a change. The impersonate = true is also in the web.config of the wwwroot. How can I figure out which httpmodule/httphandler causes this ? There is only one website and one application, and both are using the same application pool. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

What CarlosAg said. Cheap fix might be to move the favicon into the offended app rather than barking up the tree.

Answer (score 0):

I did find the answer to my problem =)

You're gonna laugh at me, for sure.. =P

Well, part of the answer is the `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />` in the C:\inetpub\wwwroot that CarlosAg pointed out, but the other part was that I simply forgot to add the `<link rel="icon" href="<%: Url.Content("~/favicon.ico")%>" type="image/x-icon" />` to my Site.Master file in my ASP.NET MVC 2 Application. Since Chrome and IE does look at the root directory for a favicon.ico, it appeared to work, but I didn't notice until now that Firefox wasn't loading up the favicon.

Now the favicon loads on every browser, and there is no 500.24 HTTP Request sent over in Fiddler.

Thanks ! =)